# Guava Cache CacheLoader.refreshAfterWrite() and .expireAfterAccess() in combination

Tags: java, caching, guava

We are using a Guava `LoadingCache` which is build by a `CacheLoader`.

What we are looking for, is a Cache which will refresh its content regularly, but also expires keys after a given (longer) timeframe, if the key is not accessed anymore.

Is it possible to use `.refresAfterWrite(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` and also `.expireAfterAccess(10,TimeUnit.MINUTES)` on the same `CacheLoader`?

My experience is that the keys are never evicted because of the regular reload through `refreshAfterWrite`. The documentation leaves me a little uncertain about this point.

Answer (score 1):

This should behave as you desired.  From the `CacheBuilder` docs:

> Currently automatic refreshes are performed when the first stale request for an entry occurs. The request triggering refresh will make a blocking call to CacheLoader.reload(K, V) and immediately return the new value if the returned future is complete, and the old value otherwise.

So if a key is queried 30 seconds after its last write, it will be refreshed; if it is not queried for 10 minutes after its last access, it will become eligible for expiration without being refreshed in the meantime.

Comment: The problem is our observations shows the following.
We get an element through the cache. It is now managed by the cache. The key is reloaded every 30 seconds through cachloader.reload().
We do not acess the key again.
The key is beeing refreshed every 30 seconds and thus never expires.

Comment: No. Eventually we dumped the guava cache and slimm down the retrieval of the objects and facilitate a lower second level cache.